# Is it possible to simulate a reboot for a serial port?

Tags: windows, powershell

Serial devices need to be installed while the PC is turned off, or rebooted if they're installed while the PC is turned on.

Is there any kind of cmd or powershell code I can execute to simulate the process of rebooting in order to refresh a serial port without having to actually reboot the machine?

Windows embedded CE 6.1.7601

PS version 5.1

Comment: Did you add the Powershell from the WinCE catalogue?

Comment: @harper yes I did

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your hardware but the short answer is ***No***. The best way to know is to test it. If you can't communicate with a device after performing a hot-plug then you need to power cycle.

The limitation you are encountering is likely a hardware limitation of the motherboard. This was true with all sorts of old hardware. Some modern systems might have ways of dealing with serial hot-plug but if your embedded system requires devices to be installed while the host is off then such is the state of things.

The only workaround is to buy hardware that is capable of serial port hot-plug.